# saving file with content as number results with NaN content

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

I have a simple script in my `nodejs` app which is managing file. When application is started it works indefinitely and on fixed intervals its saving current value (that is a `number`).

Lets say we have `counter.dat` file and its content is number `6570`.
App is launched and its working, file is being updated properly for days.
In some occasions i have to restart the process and sometimes (rarely) i find `NaN` inside instead of proper number.

I made some tests and it seems that starting file and exiting it can indeed sometimes store NaN.

```
const init = async () => {
    ...
    const readCounter = await files.getContent("counter.dat");
    ...
};

const saveCounter = (counter) => {
    // this value (counter) was never found NaN, but sometimes file has NaN inside
    let stream = fs.createWriteStream("counter.dat");
    stream.once('open', () => {
        stream.write(counter);
        stream.end();
    });
};
```

Can it be that exiting script (for example with `CTRL + C` in MAC terminal) can cause `number` to be saved as `NaN` and if so, what could be done to prevent it?

Comment: Please create a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's clear if you enter `CTRL + c` then your process will close.

You must keep your script alive even if you close the terminal.

There is a module called **[pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)**, you can start your script by *pm2*.